# Generic functions for standard deviation in monte carlo C++

Tags: c++, generic-programming, montecarlo

I am supposed to compute the standard deviation function in some monte carlo simulations. The formula is this one:
[image]

I think my results are way off what they should be. My function uses tuples from the boost library and it looks like this:

```
double add_square(double prev_sum, double new_val)
{
  return prev_sum + new_val*new_val;
}

template <typename V>
double vec_add_squares(const V<double>& v)
{
  return std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 0.0, add_square);
}

    template <class T> 
    boost::tuple<double,double> get_std_dev_and_error(const vector<T>& input, double r, double N)
{
 double M = double(input.size());

 double sum = std::accumulate(input.begin(),input.end(),0.0);
 double Squared_sum = vec_add_squares(input);

 std::cout << "sum " << Squared_sum << endl;

 // Calls Sum
 double term1 = Squared_sum - (sum/M)*sum;

 double SD = (sqrt(term1) * exp(-2.0 * r *N))/(M-1) ;
 double SE = SD/sqrt(M);
 std::cout << "SD = " << SD << endl;
 std::cout << "SE = " << SE << endl;

 return boost::tuple<double,double>(SD, SE) ;
 }
```

1. Can anyone see any mistakes here?
2. also, there is the "accumulate" funciton in the STL library - does there exist an accumulate squared (members of the container)?

Comment: For accumulate you can write your own functor

Comment: Thanks for the answer PSIA. I did write my own as in the code above but I get incorrect results, so it must be wrong or wrongly implemented in the program.

Comment: Fyi, the error indicator's *own error* can be pretty huge. Getting confidence intervals for a monte-carlo simulation is harder than usually believed.

Comment: Yes, it's quite big... the reason I know it's wrong is because I was told the results.

Comment: Maybe http://stats.stackexchange.com is a good place to ask about the computational formula?

Answer (score 4):

Just use [Boost.Accumulators](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/accumulators.html) (as you already use boost):

```
#include <boost/accumulators/accumulators.hpp>
#include <boost/accumulators/statistics.hpp>
#include <boost/range/algorithm.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>

using namespace boost;
using namespace boost::accumulators;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    accumulator_set<double, stats<tag::sum , tag::variance, tag::mean > > acc;
    double data[] = {1., 2., 3.};
    acc = for_each(data, acc);
    cout << "sum = " << sum(acc) << endl;
    cout << "variance = " << variance(acc) << endl;
    cout << "sqrt(variance()) = " << sqrt(variance(acc)) << endl;
    cout << "mean = " << mean(acc) << endl;
}
```

Output is:

```
sum = 6
variance = 0.666667
sqrt(variance()) = 0.816497
mean = 2
```

Comment: I really like Boost.Accumulators - I was a bit too fast about the standard deviation, it's not part of Accumulators (unfortunately)... I will add a picture of the formula

Comment: @Mathias: you have the variance available in `boost::accumulators`. Just take its square root (don't forget your extra factor `exp (-2rT) / (M - 1)`). Anyway, don't use the formula you posted -- it is terribly instable in many cases (boost uses a stable *on-line* fomula for the variance).

Comment: When I try to re-write the equations from http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost/accumulators/impl/variance_impl.html I still can't get the same formula as posted above (except for the exp(-2Tr) )

Comment: @AlexandreC. sorry forgot to tag you

Comment: @Mathias: Your formula reads approx. SD = sqrt (variance) * exp (-2rT) / sqrt(M - 1). There should be M /(M - 1) in front of the first sum, and the denominator ought to be M instead of M - 1 to be exactly the standard stdev estimator that you would get out of boost::accumulators. This should not change much the result however;

Comment: @AlexandreC. I know, but I was asked to code this exact formula (I would use the boost library otherwise)... I have changed my code a little bit - does this make it more stable:

Comment: @AlexandreC. I have made some modifications to my code - I think it's better now. I am supposed to use the exact formula (as given), so I can't use the boost functions.

Comment: @Mathias so does boost gives you the correct answer, but your code -incorrect? If the issue has to do with computational instability, try different statistics with both formulas - your's and boost. If the abswer will be the same then your formula is specifically bad on the initial data set.

Comment: @Riga that's good advice - thanks. I compared my simulations with other peoples' results and it turns out that I get the same results in some of the instances while totally different in other cases - really annoying.